# How do I get a sum of specific row value from each group in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have the following report setup in SSRS

[image]

Each responsible person group has three sort types, and I want the total row at the bottom to give a total for a single sort type added up for Responsible person group.

So I am trying to get to this (simplified)

[image]
And I tried using the following formula

```
=IIf(Fields!Sort.Value="Total",sum(Fields!Current.Value),0)
```

But that just gives 0. How do I set up the formulas for the Total rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my issue.  The correct code for this was

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Sort.Value = "Total",Fields!Current.Value,Nothing))
```